# .locfatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git on auto complete in bash shell

Tags: go, wsl-2

I wanted to install powershell10k for .bash on wsl2.  I did not have go installed when I ran the command

```
go get -u github.com/justjanne/powerline-go
```

and the error was fatal: not a git repo.

The issue is now, every time i start my shell, I receive 4 lines of

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

as if I am making the broken request again, but I am not. If i try to autocomplete after typing  cd /pro + TAB, i get this output, every time, regardless of what directory I am trying to auto complete:

```
cd profatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
cd profatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
jects/
```

The 'profatal' line is the start of 'projects' but when tab is used to autocomplete, that error is input instead.

Any insight into why this happened/ how I can see where the git requests are coming from would be much appreciated.

Comment: You shell is attempting to run `git` in an unexpected place, but we have no idea what that may be. If you didn't have `go` installed, then you didn't install `github.com/justjanne/powerline-go`, and the error is likely unrelated. You need to see what in your shell startup is outputting that error.

Comment: I am in the ```/home/user/``` in the subsystem. I ran go by mistake from there, trying to add powershell. When it didnt work, I installed go via sudo apt get install golang-go; this did not fix the initial error I received when running```go get -u github.com/justjanne/powerline-go``` from ```/home/user/```

Comment: Thanks for the insight but I am unsure how to see what would be prompting the error when it occurs on startup before I have run any commands via bash. The error is the same one I immediately received when I tried to ```go get``` the powershell repo from github. Never have had that before and now it won't reset so I know definitively that the error I am getting both on start and on auto complete is tied to the initial ```go get``` request. I am unsure how go interacts with git as this was only used to install an aesthetic package.

Answer (score 0):

Commented out the below lines in .bashrc to fix autocompletion issue that arose from invalid command I entered. There were likely additions to the config files when go was added and that changed how my prompt and shell were configured:

Thanks @JimB for the help.

```
# if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#   if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#     . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#   elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#     . /etc/bash_completion
#   fi
# fi
```